# Point 2 A Records to IP address, separate folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, a-records

I have 2 separate A records pointing to the same IP address:

example1.domain.com -> IP
example2.domain.com -> IP

"example1.domain.com" currently points to the root public_html folder (where wordpress is installed)

I would like the second, "example2.domain.com" to end up in:

public_html/example2folder  - (where i have installed magento)

How do I edit the .htaccess file correctly to achieve this? Please help!

Comment: You don't do this (or shouldn't do this) in .htaccess I think. You need to edit httpd.conf.

Comment: If you are on a shared hosting, you should be able to set this from the control panel and it cannot be set in the .htaccess.

Otherwise take a look at virtual hosts - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Comment: Here is where I am at. I have an ecommerce site setup on a host that will not allow installation of other platforms such as wordpress or magento. i setup an A record for "blog.mydomain.com" and have that pointing to an ip address on a new server with wordpress. it works great. Now i want to add another A record to that same IP address, but instead of pulling the blog also, pull a magento site installed in a subfolder

Comment: i should mention the IP address i am pointing to is a godaddy server

Comment: These are official instructions from godaddy, on how you can add two domains to one hosting account - https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5399/hosting-multiple-websites-on-your-hosting-account

Comment: My domain is primarily hosted on Volusion. I have setup an A record there that points to a godaddy ip address.